# How do a Bottom Menu that expand - Flutter

Tags: flutter

How do I this bottom bar menu in Flutter?

[bottom menu hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj85c.png)

[bottom menu opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfLBc.png)

There is a bar at bottom and when tapped, the bar is opened with a list and a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `BottomSheet` here's example :

```
void _modalBottomSheetMenu(BuildContext context){
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (builder){
      return ListView(
        children: [
          ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(),
            title: Text("John Doe"),
            subtitle: Text("Nearby"),
          ),
          RaisedButton(child: Text("Button"), onPressed: () => print("Pressed"))
        ]
      );
    }
  );
}
```

For more information [Flutter Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html) , [Medium Guide](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-beginners-guide-to-using-the-bottom-sheet-b8025573c433)

Answer (score 0):

Identify status e.g. isExpanded

then display your cells(Widgets) based on that. Either you can use Visibility widget,

```
Visibility(
  visible: (isExpanded),
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
     Image.asset('yourImage')
     Text("some text"),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Or you can just use a condition like,

```
if (a == b)
    Row(
        children: <Widget>[
         Image.asset('yourImage')
         Text("some text"),
        ],
      ),
```